# CSS Grid not workiing on IE11 or Edge even with -ms prefix

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge, css-grid

I've been following the guide [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh673533%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) on getting grids working on IE 11. My problem is that even following those rules, the columns and rows just overlap each other rather than taking their grid positions.

Here's a simple code example that would cause the problem:

HTML

```
<div class="grid">
  <div>Top Left</div>
  <div>Top Right</div>
  <div>Bottom Left</div>
  <div>Bottom Right</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.grid {
  display: -ms-grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: 200px 200px;
  -ms-grid-rows: 200px 200px;
}
```

And here's a codepen link to it:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pdNWMj

Am I getting this code wrong, or should I be using something other than the ms implementation of grid?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You must use `-ms-grid-column` and `-ms-grid-row` to specify for each child where it is in the grid.

```css
.grid {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: 200px 200px;
  -ms-grid-rows: 200px 200px;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 200px;
  grid-template-rows: 200px 200px;
}

.top-left {
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
  -ms-grid-row: 1;
}

.top-right {
  -ms-grid-column: 2;
  -ms-grid-row: 1;
}

.bottom-left {
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
  -ms-grid-row: 2;
}

.bottom-right {
  -ms-grid-column: 2;
  -ms-grid-row: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="top-left">Top Left</div>
  <div class="top-right">Top Right</div>
  <div class="bottom-left">Bottom Left</div>
  <div class="bottom-right">Bottom Right</div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZaBaVa

Not as convenient as the other browsers... 
Hoping this helps though ;)

Comment: Thank you so much. I had already tried this, but thinking back I must have accidentally started my indexes at 0 instead of 1.